# Angular2 Unit Test Mouse Events

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I want to test one of methods which helps in closing Modal Window when closed outside of Modal Window container.

**Component Method**

```
public hide(): void {
    this.visibleAnimate = false;
    setTimeout(() => { this.visible = false; }, 200);
  }

public onModalClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.contains('dialog-container')) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
```

**Unit Test**

```
it('should call hide method', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.hide();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.visible).toEqual(false);
      tick(200);
      expect(component.visibleAnimate).toEqual(false);
    });
  }));



it('should call onModalClicked()', () => {
    const mockEvent = new Event('click'); --> Error
    component.onModalClicked(mockEvent);
    console.log(component.visible);
  });
```

My Unit test runs fine on `hide()` method and please let me know if i am doing it in right way or not.

But i am really stuck how to test `onModalClicked()` method because that takes *MouseEvent* as parameter.

> In my unit testing method, Event and MouseEvent mismatch error occurs, which is obviouse biut how to cover this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't need to actually *be* a `MouseEvent`, it just needs to [quack like one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). So you can just make a dummy object that fits the bill and cast it to `MouseEvent` so it fits your method parameter type. For example:

```
function createMouseEvent(hasClass, clazz): MouseEvent {
  const event = { target: { classList: { contains: (arg) => false } } }
  if (hasClass) {
    event.target.classList.contains = (cls) => {
      expect(cls).toBe(clazz)
      return true
    }
  } 
  return <any>event;
}
```

Then to test it, you don't need to actually test the visibility. That is the job of the `hide` method (to change the visibility). You just want to test the `behavior` of the `onModalClicked`, which is that it either calls `hide` or doesn't, based on the element containing a class. So you can just [spy](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) on the `hide` function, then check if it was called.

```
it('onModalClicked() should call hide() when element contains class', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'hide')
  const event = createMouseEvent(true, 'dialog-container');
  component.onModalClicked(event);

  expect(component.hide).toHaveBeenCalled()
})

it('onModalClicked() should NOT call hide() when element DOES NOT contain class', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'hide')
  const event = createMouseEvent(false, null);
  component.onModalClicked(event);

  expect(component.hide).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: I think it is the best suited solution. And cAn you please confirm if i have written correct test case for hide method

Comment: You don't need `fixture.whenStable`. You are using `fakeAsync`. It is only needed for `async`

Comment: Does the logic for test looks fine? And instead of calling specific method to test, why fixture.detectChanges() does not test those methods?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Maybe you should do some more research on what fixture.detectChanges actually does.

Comment: `createMouseEvent` function does no work in Typescript. it shows an error `Property 'contains' does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: You can just add it. `classList: { contains: () => false }`. If you initialize it like this, then you can actually just leave out the `else`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150245/discussion-between-gags-and-peeskillet).